# returning font from C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, css, model-view-controller, fonts

I want to use a custom font in my CSS with `@font-face`, the problem is that when I use a url, like from google fonts, there is no problem:

```
/* arabic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Arabic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/notosansarabic/v18/nwpxtLGrOAZMl5nJ_wfgRg3DrWFZWsnVBJ_sS6tlqHHFlhQ5l3sQWIHPqzCfyG2fuXqA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0600-06FF, U+0750-077F, U+0870-088E, U+0890-0891, U+0898-08E1, U+08E3-08FF, U+200C-200E, U+2010-2011, U+204F, U+2E41, U+FB50-FDFF, U+FE70-FE74, U+FE76-FEFC, U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

but when I use the generated link from my C# MVC function it's not working.

```
/* arabic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Arabic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(url/generated/with/c#/mvc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0600-06FF, U+0750-077F, U+0870-088E, U+0890-0891, U+0898-08E1, U+08E3-08FF, U+200C-200E, U+2010-2011, U+204F, U+2E41, U+FB50-FDFF, U+FE70-FE74, U+FE76-FEFC, U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

And here's the function I've written in C#:

```
        public ActionResult Action(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                //path = @"C:\Users\mohammadreza.rahbari\AppData\Local\QlikTech\QlikView\Extensions\Objects\" + path;

                var name = path.Split('\\').Last();

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    return null;

                var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                fileStream.Position = 0;

                var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(name);
                var result = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType)
                {
                    FileDownloadName = name
                };
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The font from google font is making effect but when I get it from my own url, it is not making any effects. url given from the function is working correctly because I can download the font from it. @Yogi